# Storage limits in GB of Google Music

Tags: google-play-music

How much space is available for me to store and uplad MP3s to the Google Music service?

Will I also be able to download music from there? I was also thinking of syncing it up with an iPhone/iPad if that was possible.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Online sources](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/Music-Beta-streaming-cloud-storage-web-player-digital-music,news-11303.html) state that the service is limited by number of songs rather than a specific file size limit:

   > The company boasted a capacity of up to 20,000 songs that users can max out for free until the beta tag is finally dropped at an undisclosed date
2. The same source states:

   > **The library is accessible from any computer**, but locked down to eight external devices
3. As to how to play music on your iPod Touch or iPad there is a guide [here](http://www.techoncept.com/how-to-use-google-music-on-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch) that basically tells you to point your Safari browser at the music site and just click "play"...